# Not able to open more than 4 instance of internet explorer while using Selenium Bindings for Python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python code to open multiple instances of Internet Explorer at same time.
This is done by threading.
But the problem is I am not able open more than 4 internet explorer windows at same time.
I am not using selenium grid, just selenium module. Also I am not running the selenium standalone server.

The code will open 4 explorer and then closes it. After one of them is closed 5th explorer is opened.

Comment: IE has problems.  With IE11 and Selenium Grid I can get 5 at a time, but ultimately above this the OS/IEDriver has problems with keeping the multiple browsers separate.  The solution we used is to utilize GRID and then have 3 hubs with 5 each...giving 15 total at a time.

This works, but I wouldn't call it a "solution" as much as a work around.  I'm unsure if there is actually a solution as this affects OS/Browser functionality with IEDriver...there are already a couple of shaky aspects to IEDriver and IE.

Comment: Thanks Mutt... I tired with IE8, its working fine in IE 8